# How to write a unix shell script to to delete files(1.f1,2.f2,) in a directory

Tags: shell, unix

How to write a unix program to to delete files(1.f1,2.f2,3.f3) in a directory  by giving  serial number assigned to files respectively as input from keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I think with following commands you can archive what you want:

- `read`: to read user's input and assign value to a variable.
- `rm`: to delete file.

Answer (score 0):

Reading input from user and deleting all files that contain the user input as file name in the current dir :

```
echo Please enter serial :
read serial
rm -f *"$serial"*
```

if the serial is in the file contents instead, you can use this instead of the rm command (Eg to search the contents of the files)

```
for f in $(grep -l "$serial" *) ; do rm -f $f; echo "$f deleted"; done
```